# Maui ScrollView - Scrollbar length not updating when content dynamically changed

Tags: c#, maui

I tried [this content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/scrollview) with TwoWay mode.
I used ObservableCollection, when I modify the content is updated, but the scroll length is not updated.

[image: ![scrollview content is too long]

Right Scrollbar is too long.
How can I update the scrollbar length?

```xml
<ScrollView BackgroundColor="LightGray" x:Name="InfoStack">
        <StackLayout
            BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:InfoHelpers.Ints}, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <.../>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It behavior differently on different platforms .

I did test your code on `Windows desktop` , `iOS` and `Android` simulator .

The result is that it only works on **Windows desktop**, ScrollView does not expand dynamatically as expected on iOS and Android .

It seems like a `potential issue` , consider rainsing the issue on github :https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues .

#### Workaround

Use `CollectionView` instead of `ScrollView`.

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:InfoHelpers.Ints}, Mode=TwoWay}">
   <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>      
          <Label Text="{Binding .}" HeightRequest="40"/>             
      </DataTemplate>
   </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Answer (score 2):

After changing content, this *might* fix it:

```cs
(InfoStack as IView).InvalidateArrange();
```

---

**UPDATE BASED ON COMMENT**

Instead use:

```cs
(InfoStack as IView).InvalidateMeasure();
```

Comment: I had to use `InvalidateMeasure` but it worked.

Comment: Good to know. Did that work by itself, or did it require BOTH Measure/Arrange (and if so, in which order)?

Comment: all it took was `_container.InvalidateMeasure();` And It did not need a delay.